# Тракторы или трактора?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Какой вариант является правильным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выдержка из Малого академического словаря:

> ТРА́КТОР, -а, мн. *тра́ктор**ы*** и *трактор**а́***, м.

Таким образом, верны оба варианта.